# How to create one attribute containing multiple adjacent parcels?

Tags: fields-attributes, dissolve, multipart

I'm trying to upload town parcel data to my Garmin GPS from Esri. Garmin registers each attribute as an entirely different file, and requires you to 'turn on' each file to display it on the GPS. This means I would have to click through thousands of parcels to display an entire town's data on my GPS.

I would like to create one attribute with multiple (1000+) adjacent parcels in order to successfully upload parcel data onto a GPS. Is this possible?

From what I understand, you can't create a multipart feature with shared boundaries.